# Query performance drop after upgrade to MariaDB 10.5 (group_concat + join)

Tags: performance, mariadb, performance-tuning

We have upgrade our database servers and are experiencing some performance issue.

Some complex queries, with lots of join and group_concat are 30% to 60% slower than on our old servers.
(Same query with the same data and same server load)

Old servers :

- Intel Xeon E3-1270 with 32 Gb RAM + nvme
- MariaDB 10.2.12
- Only InnoDB
- query_cache_type OFF (galera best practice)
- innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20 G

New Servers :

- AMD Epyc 7371 with 128 Gb RAM + nvme
- MariaDB 10.5.8
- Only InnoDB
- query_cache_type OFF (galera best practice)
- innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100 G (far from beeing saturated)

Almost all the others variables are set to their default value or have the same values beetween those servers.

**I am almost sure that I have missed something**, but I didn't find a way to get the same level of performance.

Because our queries are really complex, I tried to reproduce this behaviour on a **simplified environnement**.

On a vanilla docker container of MariaDB 10.4.16 vs 10.5.8 I have almost the same performance gap with some join and group_concat.
The query below si executed :

- MariaDB 10.4.16: **2.45 sec**
- MariaDB 10.5.8 : **3.3 sec**

Here is a Gist with the reproductible case : https://gist.github.com/FelV/aa0be4db42101dff080fa760ee742d6f

The test dummy irrelevant Query:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
        'A',
        (SELECT aname from activity aa
            where aa.person_id = persons.id
            order by aa.id desc limit 1)
    )
)
FROM persons 
LEFT JOIN activity ON activity.person_id = persons.id
LEFT JOIN persons persons_plus ON persons_plus.id = activity.acode
GROUP BY persons.id
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
maria10416:
    image: mariadb:10.4.16
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root         
        MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    volumes:
        - ./setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
        - ./99-custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/hostconf/99-custom.cnf
    command: >
      bash -c "
      cp /etc/mysql/hostconf/*.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
      && chmod 644 /etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf
      && docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
      "
maria1058:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8
    ports:
        - 3307:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root         
        MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    volumes:
        - ./setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
        - ./99-custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/hostconf/99-custom.cnf
    command: >
      bash -c "
      cp /etc/mysql/hostconf/*.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
      && chmod 644 /etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf
      && docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
      "
```

setup.sql (Data seeder)

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'%'=PASSWORD('');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

USE mydb;

CREATE TABLE persons (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    code INT(6) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL    
);

CREATE TABLE activity (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    person_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
    acode INT(6) NOT NULL,
    aname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    INDEX IDX_person_id (person_id ASC)    
);



DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS seedProc;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE seedProc()   
BEGIN   
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0; 

    START TRANSACTION;

    WHILE (i <= 1000) DO
        INSERT INTO `persons` (code, name) values (i, CONCAT("My Name ", i));        

        SET j = 0;
        WHILE (j <= 1000) DO
            INSERT INTO `activity` (person_id, acode, aname) values (i, j, CONCAT("Activity ",j, " from user ", i));
            SET j = j + 1;        
        END WHILE;

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END;
//  

CALL seedProc();
```

99-custom.cnf

```
[mysqld]

query_cache_size      = 0
query_cache_type      = 0
innodb_doublewrite    = 1
```

test.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

QUERY=$(cat <<QUERY
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
        'A',
        (SELECT aname from activity aa where aa.person_id = persons.id order by aa.id desc limit 1)
    )
)
FROM persons 
LEFT JOIN activity ON activity.person_id = persons.id
LEFT JOIN persons persons_plus ON persons_plus.id = activity.acode
GROUP BY persons.id
QUERY
)

echo "MariaDB 10.4.16 : "
time echo "$QUERY" | mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3306 mydb  > /dev/null

echo "MariaDB 10.5.8 : "
time echo "$QUERY" | mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3307 mydb  > /dev/null
```

Result :

```
MariaDB 10.4.16 :

real    0m2.430s
user    0m0.127s
sys     0m0.005s
MariaDB 10.5.8 :

real    0m3.345s
user    0m0.128s
sys     0m0.009s
```

Do someone have a clue of a variable that could have an impact on such a query ?

Edit :

### MariaDB 10.4.16 Explain :

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | persons | index | \N | PRIMARY | 4 | \N | 895 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | activity | ref | IDX_person_id | IDX_person_id | 4 | mydb.persons.id | 500 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | aa | ref | IDX_person_id | IDX_person_id | 4 | mydb.persons.id | 500 | Using where |

### MariaDB 10.5.8 Explain :

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | persons | index | \N | PRIMARY | 4 | \N | 901 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | activity | ref | IDX_person_id | IDX_person_id | 4 | mydb.persons.id | 500 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | aa | ref | IDX_person_id | IDX_person_id | 4 | mydb.persons.id | 500 | Using where |

Comment: Can you obtain EXPLAINs for both servers?

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I added the explain from both servers.

Comment: Plans are identical, so the difference in tables statistic is not a root of the problem.

Comment: Suggest filing a bug report with MariaDB.  (Performance regressions are embarrassing.)

Comment: Are the outputs the same?

Comment: Outputs are identical.

Comment: @Phil I know I am very late but if you created a bug report with Mariadb, could you please put link to it as I am experiencing similar performance issue